# Why do I need to save handle to an old bitmap while drawing with Win32 GDI?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi, handle

Here is the code from switch in WndProc function I've been given as an example:

```
case WM_PAINT:
 hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
 // Create a system memory device context.
 bmHDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
// Hook up the bitmap to the bmHDC.
 oldBM = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(bmHDC, ghBitMap);
 // Now copy the pixels from the bitmap bmHDC has selected
 // to the pixels from the client area hdc has selected.
 BitBlt(
 hdc, // Destination DC.
 0, // 'left' coordinate of destination rectangle.
 0, // 'top' coordinate of destination rectangle.
 bmWidth, // 'right' coordinate of destination rectangle.
 bmHeight, // 'bottom' coordinate of destination rectangle.
 bmHDC, // Bitmap source DC.
 0, // 'left' coordinate of source rectangle.
 0, // 'top' coordinate of source rectangle.
 SRCCOPY); // Copy the source pixels directly
 // to the destination pixels
 // Select the originally loaded bitmap.
 SelectObject(bmHDC, oldBM);
 // Delete the system memory device context.
 DeleteDC(bmHDC);
 EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
 return 0;
```

My question is why is it necessary to save and restore the return value of SelectObject() in oldBM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is it necessary to save and restore the return value of SelectObject() in oldBM?

`BeginPaint()` gives you an `HDC` that already has a default `HBITMAP` selected into it.  You are then replacing that with your own `HBITMAP`.  You did not allocate the original `HBITMAP` and do not own it, `BeginPaint()` allocated it.  You must restore the original `HBITMAP` when you are done using the `HDC` so that `EndPaint()` can free it when destroying the `HDC`, otherwise it will be leaked.

Comment: Worse than leaking a bitmap resource is the double-delete: If you play by the rules, and dispose off your bitmap resource (that is still selected into a device context), the system will do the same, when the `WM_PAINT` handler returns.